# Rewrite Domain Name to a Capitalized CamelCase Name with Nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, domain-name

This Issue is based on pure aesthetics, i have a Domain "CertainDomain" and have all Logos etc. Designed to be written in CamelCase.

Now i'd really like to see that Domain-Name in my Adress-Bar in CamelCase after the redirect from http to https.
With Nginx i have not been successfull so far.

**My Question is, is this even possible with 301 Responses and modern Browsers?

And if so, is Nginx able to do it?**

My redirect:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name certaindomain.com ;
    return 301 https://CertainDomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

I know that DNS doesn't care for such things, as i said, pure aesthetics.

Comment: What happens if you setup the redirect that way?

Comment: not that it's important to the Q or A, but that's not strictly camel case, it's title case. eg TitleCase vs camelCase ..camels only have a hump in the middle ;)

Comment: You can't do this. The hostname is not case sensitive. The browser will just complain about too many redirects.

Comment: @Seth: The redirect works just fine but no Browser i tried adopts the TitleCase. However with the Statements so far i think i have to settle without this feature, not that it is a big issue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [RFC 4343: Domain Name System (DNS) Case Insensitivity Clarification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4343):

> According to the original DNS design decision, comparisons on name
> lookup for DNS queries should be case insensitive [STD13].  That is
> to say, a lookup string octet with a value in the inclusive range
> from 0x41 to 0x5A, the uppercase ASCII letters, MUST match the
> identical value and also match the corresponding value in the
> inclusive range from 0x61 to 0x7A, the lowercase ASCII letters.  A
> lookup string octet with a lowercase ASCII letter value MUST
> similarly match the identical value and also match the corresponding
> value in the uppercase ASCII letter range.

Even if you might be able to setup a 301 it would likely be up to the browser to decide what to make of it. Depending on the kind of domain there might be some exceptions but if your domain "just" uses regular ASCII characters you might not be able to force this.